# Error while rendering an array from firestore to react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i have an array that i am trying to read and store in a state however, with the code below, here is the error i get: "function collectionReferenace.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was undefined" any idea why this is happening and what is the solution?

```
componentDidMount(){
        dbh.collection('Groups').doc(this.props.route.params.groupName)
        .collection('Enrolled').doc('ids').get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot(doc => {
                this.setState({
                    playerIDs: doc.data().players
                })
            })
        })
        console.log(this.state.playerIDs)
    }
```

the `this.props.route.params.groupName` is passed from the navigation of the previous screen. When I set a constant in the render function to it and call that variable it works fine.

```
    render() {
    const groupName = this.props.route.params.groupTitle
return
<Text>{groupName}</Text>
```

for your reference, here is how i am getting that route.param

```
<GroupComponent onPress = {
() => this.props.navigation.navigate
('Attendance', {groupTitle: group.GroupName, groupID: group.id})
} />
```

Comment: The error means that the `this.props.route.params.groupName` is null (or undefined). Print out value of  `this.props.route.params.groupName` just to check and tell me what it is. It will be undefined, what do you expect it to be and how do you get the value?

Comment: yes you are right. I have got undefined when i console logged it.

Comment: Okay, which means  `this.props.route.params.groupName` is null. So how do you get that value and what do you expect it to be? Add the code to the question.

Comment: this.props.route.params.groupName has been passed through the navigate as it is the title of a selected group.

Comment: Add all the code relevant to that variable ( `this.props.route.params.groupName`) to your question, so I can see what's making it undefined please. Also try hard coding a value into `.doc(this.props.route.params.groupName)` and see if you get is what's expected.

Comment: in the render function, im am able to set a constant to it and console log that constant

Comment: I can't comment much without any code

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you should be acccessing `dbh.collection('Groups').doc(this.props.route.params.groupTitle)` not `groupName`. The object you pass through params has keys `groupTitle` and and `groupID`, not `groupName`.